# How to automatically pause a GPS tracker when user is not moving

Tags: ios, swift, gps, battery

I have a two part question (1) How to pause activity tracking when user is not moving, (2) and can this save battery life?

A bit more information. I'm building an activity tracker but for an activity that typically involve a lot of pausing - eg. walk for 30 minutes, waiting at a location for 60-120 minutes, then walk again for 30 minutes etc.

As the overall tracking can take up to 3-4 hours, it would be useful to reduce battery consumption as much as possible. It would also be good that the polyline of the activity do not include a lot of forth and back due to GPS inaccuracy while user is at a given location for a longer period of time.

So back to the questions. (1) How to use swift to identify when user is standing still, and pause polyline tracking (2) will this save battery life?

Comment: If you pause location updates, how will you know if the user starts moving again?

Answer (score 1):

You should look into `startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges()` ([documentation here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/cllocationmanager/1423531-startmonitoringsignificantlocati)).

This description from the above link appears to fit your need:

> After returning a current location fix, the receiver generates update
>   events only when a significant change in the user’s location is
>   detected.

You will likely want to include this check as well to make sure you can make use of the above function:

[significantLocationChangeMonitoringAvailable()](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/cllocationmanager/1423677-significantlocationchangemonitor)

> Returns a Boolean value indicating whether the significant-change
>   location service is available.

Comment: This would be my suggestion too, but be aware that the user may have to move up to 500m before significant location monitoring will fire an update.

Comment: @Paulw11 Agreed, but the comment "then walk again for 30 minutes" implies some distance will be covered.

Comment: Yes, I am not criticising your approach.  I just wanted the OP to be aware of this.  They haven't indicated how accurate the data needs to be; a straight line distance inferred from a significant location update can be quite different from the actual distance travelled along streets etc.

Comment: Hi, looked into this further for my need it might be better to use the motion data from the accelerometer to detect whether the user is moving or not. If no/limited motion is captured for eg. 30 seconds initiate pause (GPS off to save battery life), when motion is captures for 5-10 seconds the turn GPS back on. 

Do anyone have any experience for what rules to use turn pause on/off in the most user friendly way. Dont want to pause to often, or restart tracking too late...